# How to interact with .NET object methods from powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, elasticsearch, nest

How to call method of .NET object in powershell (Elasticsearch NEST .NET client). This is basic example of .NET code for NEST client and I am trying to write PS equivalent but I am failing in setting object value. Is this even possible to do with .NET object in powershell?

**.NET**

```
var config = new Nest.ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection)
.DefaultIndex("employee_data"); //complete extensions omitted for brevity
```

**Powershell**

```
$config = new-object -Type Nest.ConnectionSettings($pool, $httpConnection)
$config.DefaultIndex("mate")
Method invocation failed because [Nest.ConnectionSettings] does not contain a method named 'DefaultIndex'.

$config | gm



   TypeName: Nest.ConnectionSettings

Name                                MemberType Definition                                                                                                                                                      
----                                ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                      
ApiKeyAuthentication                Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ApiKeyAuthentication(string id, securestring apiKey), Nest.ConnectionSettings ApiKeyAuthentication(string id, string apiKey), Nest.Co...
BasicAuthentication                 Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings BasicAuthentication(string username, string password), Nest.ConnectionSettings BasicAuthentication(string username, securestring pass...
ClientCertificate                   Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ClientCertificate(X509Certificate certificate), Nest.ConnectionSettings ClientCertificate(string certificatePath)                       
ClientCertificates                  Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ClientCertificates(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection certificates)                                
ConnectionLimit                     Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ConnectionLimit(int connectionLimit)                                                                                                    
DeadTimeout                         Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DeadTimeout(timespan timeout)                                                                                                           
DefaultDisableIdInference           Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DefaultDisableIdInference(bool disable)                                                                                                 
DefaultFieldNameInferrer            Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DefaultFieldNameInferrer(System.Func[string,string] fieldNameInferrer)                                                                  
DefaultIndex                        Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DefaultIndex(string defaultIndex)                                                                                                       
DefaultMappingFor                   Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DefaultMappingFor[TDocument](System.Func[Nest.ClrTypeMappingDescriptor[TDocument],Nest.IClrTypeMapping[TDocument]] selector), Nest.Co...
DisableAutomaticProxyDetection      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DisableAutomaticProxyDetection(bool disable)                                                                                            
DisableDirectStreaming              Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DisableDirectStreaming(bool b)                                                                                                          
DisableMetaHeader                   Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DisableMetaHeader(bool disable)                                                                                                         
DisablePing                         Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DisablePing(bool disable)                                                                                                               
Dispose                             Method     void IDisposable.Dispose()                                                                                                                                      
DnsRefreshTimeout                   Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings DnsRefreshTimeout(timespan timeout)                                                                                                     
EnableApiVersioningHeader           Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableApiVersioningHeader(bool enable)                                                                                                  
EnableDebugMode                     Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableDebugMode(System.Action[Elasticsearch.Net.IApiCallDetails] onRequestCompleted)                                                    
EnableHttpCompression               Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableHttpCompression(bool enabled)                                                                                                     
EnableHttpPipelining                Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableHttpPipelining(bool enabled)                                                                                                      
EnableTcpKeepAlive                  Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableTcpKeepAlive(timespan keepAliveTime, timespan keepAliveInterval)                                                                  
EnableTcpStats                      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableTcpStats(bool enableTcpStats)                                                                                                     
EnableThreadPoolStats               Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings EnableThreadPoolStats(bool enableThreadPoolStats)                                                                                       
Equals                              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                                  
GetHashCode                         Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                               
GetType                             Method     type GetType()                                                                                                                                                  
GlobalHeaders                       Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings GlobalHeaders(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers)                                                               
GlobalQueryStringParameters         Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings GlobalQueryStringParameters(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection queryStringParameters)                                   
IncludeServerStackTraceOnError      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings IncludeServerStackTraceOnError(bool b)                                                                                                  
MaxDeadTimeout                      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings MaxDeadTimeout(timespan timeout)                                                                                                        
MaximumRetries                      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings MaximumRetries(int maxRetries)                                                                                                          
MaxRetryTimeout                     Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings MaxRetryTimeout(timespan maxRetryTimeout)                                                                                               
MemoryStreamFactory                 Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings MemoryStreamFactory(Elasticsearch.Net.IMemoryStreamFactory memoryStreamFactory)                                                         
NodePredicate                       Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings NodePredicate(System.Func[Elasticsearch.Net.Node,bool] predicate)                                                                       
OnRequestCompleted                  Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings OnRequestCompleted(System.Action[Elasticsearch.Net.IApiCallDetails] handler)                                                            
OnRequestDataCreated                Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings OnRequestDataCreated(System.Action[Elasticsearch.Net.RequestData] handler)                                                              
PingTimeout                         Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings PingTimeout(timespan timeout)                                                                                                           
PrettyJson                          Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings PrettyJson(bool b)                                                                                                                      
Proxy                               Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings Proxy(uri proxyAddress, string username, string password), Nest.ConnectionSettings Proxy(uri proxyAddress, string username, securestr...
RequestTimeout                      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings RequestTimeout(timespan timeout)                                                                                                        
ServerCertificateValidationCallback Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ServerCertificateValidationCallback(System.Func[System.Object,X509Certificate,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain...
SkipDeserializationForStatusCodes   Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings SkipDeserializationForStatusCodes(Params int[] statusCodes)                                                                             
SniffLifeSpan                       Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings SniffLifeSpan(System.Nullable[timespan] sniffLifeSpan)                                                                                  
SniffOnConnectionFault              Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings SniffOnConnectionFault(bool sniffsOnConnectionFault)                                                                                    
SniffOnStartup                      Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings SniffOnStartup(bool sniffsOnStartup)                                                                                                    
ThrowExceptions                     Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings ThrowExceptions(bool alwaysThrow)                                                                                                       
ToString                            Method     string ToString()                                                                                                                                               
TransferEncodingChunked             Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings TransferEncodingChunked(bool transferEncodingChunked)                                                                                   
UserAgent                           Method     Nest.ConnectionSettings UserAgent(string userAgent)                                                                                                             
ApiKeyAuthenticationCredentials     Property   Elasticsearch.Net.ApiKeyAuthenticationCredentials ApiKeyAuthenticationCredentials {get;}                                                                        
BasicAuthenticationCredentials      Property   Elasticsearch.Net.BasicAuthenticationCredentials BasicAuthenticationCredentials {get;}                                                                          
BootstrapLock                       Property   System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim BootstrapLock {get;}                                                                                                             
Connection                          Property   Elasticsearch.Net.IConnection Connection {get;}                                                                                                                 
ConnectionPool                      Property   Elasticsearch.Net.IConnectionPool ConnectionPool {get;}                                                                                                         
DefaultIndices                      Property   Nest.FluentDictionary[type,string] DefaultIndices {get;}                                                                                                        
DefaultRelationNames                Property   Nest.FluentDictionary[type,string] DefaultRelationNames {get;}                                                                                                  
DisableIdInference                  Property   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[type] DisableIdInference {get;}                                                                                              
DisablePings                        Property   bool DisablePings {get;}                                                                                                                                        
Headers                             Property   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Headers {get;}                                                                                               
HttpPipeliningEnabled               Property   bool HttpPipeliningEnabled {get;}                                                                                                                               
IdProperties                        Property   Nest.FluentDictionary[type,string] IdProperties {get;}                                                                                                          
Inferrer                            Property   Nest.Inferrer Inferrer {get;}                                                                                                                                   
KeepAliveInterval                   Property   System.Nullable[timespan] KeepAliveInterval {get;}                                                                                                              
KeepAliveTime                       Property   System.Nullable[timespan] KeepAliveTime {get;}                                                                                                                  
MaxRetries                          Property   System.Nullable[int] MaxRetries {get;}                                                                                                                          
MetaHeaderProvider                  Property   Elasticsearch.Net.MetaHeaderProvider MetaHeaderProvider {get;}                                                                                                  
PropertyMappingProvider             Property   Nest.IPropertyMappingProvider PropertyMappingProvider {get;}                                                                                                    
PropertyMappings                    Property   Nest.FluentDictionary[System.Reflection.MemberInfo,Nest.IPropertyMapping] PropertyMappings {get;}                                                               
ProxyAddress                        Property   string ProxyAddress {get;}                                                                                                                                      
ProxyPassword                       Property   securestring ProxyPassword {get;}                                                                                                                               
ProxyUsername                       Property   string ProxyUsername {get;}                                                                                                                                     
QueryStringParameters               Property   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection QueryStringParameters {get;}                                                                                 
RequestResponseSerializer           Property   Elasticsearch.Net.IElasticsearchSerializer RequestResponseSerializer {get;}                                                                                     
RouteProperties                     Property   Nest.FluentDictionary[type,string] RouteProperties {get;}                                                                                                       
SniffInformationLifeSpan            Property   System.Nullable[timespan] SniffInformationLifeSpan {get;}                                                                                                       
SniffsOnConnectionFault             Property   bool SniffsOnConnectionFault {get;}                                                                                                                             
SniffsOnStartup                     Property   bool SniffsOnStartup {get;}                                                                                                                                     
SourceSerializer                    Property   Elasticsearch.Net.IElasticsearchSerializer SourceSerializer {get;}                                                                                              
StatusCodeToResponseSuccess         Property   System.Func[Elasticsearch.Net.HttpMethod,int,bool] StatusCodeToResponseSuccess {get;}                                                                           
UrlFormatter                        Property   Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchUrlFormatter
```

So as you see, Method DefaultIndex is there, so I am confused by this error.

Comment: Can you try running `$config.DefaultIndex` alone as a property and not a method and print the error you receive or the overloads shown in the output?

Comment: that runs OK, but no value since it's not set

Comment: @opti2k4, if `$config.DefaultIndex` produces no output, that suggests that it behaves like a _property_, not like a _method_ - if it behaved like a method,  you'd see the method _signature(s)_ (as shown in your `Get-Member` output). If you add `-Force` to the `Get-Member` call, do additional relevant entries appear?

Comment: I do see a lot more entries, but still not sure what to do with those..
                                                           
`get_DefaultIndex                        Method       string IConnectionSettingsValues.get_DefaultIndex()` I would assume I can only get this and not set it?

Comment: `DefaultIndex   Method   Nest.ConnectionSettings DefaultIndex(string defaultIndex) `

Answer (score 0):

```
$config.GetType().GetMethod("DefaultIndex").Invoke($config, "some_index")
```

:( not very intuitive way to do this